# Проблема с последней колонкой в таблице при вёрстке дивами

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Вторая колонка не доходит до конца. Нужно сделать так, чтобы не задавая последней колонке размеров, она сама доходила до конца.

```
.table .column2_title {
    float: left;
}
```

**jsfiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/5mHBM/

Comment: @dekameron, разве это нормально? Везде есть float, а в последнем столбце убираем его?

Comment: @ModaL, как видите, нормально :)
Итого все колонки "складываются" к левому краю, а последння отображается без float, занимая все свободное пространство

Comment: @dekameron, да, всё отлично. Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы я мог проголосовать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dekameron/5mHBM/1/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table .column {
  background: #e3e9ee;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.table .column1_title {
  float: left;
  background: #e3e9ee;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  width: 35%;
}
.table .column2_title {
  float: left;
}
/* added */

.table .column:last-child {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column column1_title">Колонка 1</div>
  <div class="column column2_title">Колонка 2</div>
</div>
```